# Why FCM not working on android device in flutter application?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I currently create a chat application and I try to implement the notification system when an user receive a new incoming message.

It's work perfectly on iOS devices, but not work on android device.

Thanks for your help,

I tried to request a notification permission to a user. But on android device I didn't have any pop up spawn on the screen. I added firebasemessaging.onmessage.listen to try to fix the bug, but it did not work.

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

class PermissionService {
  Future<void> notification() async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) {
      print("A new message event was published");
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((event) {
      print("A new OpenedAppMessage event was published");
    });
  }
}
```

That is my get fcm token function. The goal of the method is get a fcm token of the device. This function work perfectly, because I can see the fcm token of the android device inside my database.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

class FCMService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<void> createFcmToken() async {
    final User? user = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    final fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();

    if (user != null) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("fcm_token")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .set({
        "fcm_token": fcmToken,
        "user_id": user.uid,
      });
    }
  }
}
```

On this image, I can see the cloud function start, and send the notification with fcm token

[firebase cloud function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj3zM.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when app running on **foreground**, FCM android didnt popup notification. it already mentioned on the documentation https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications#android-configuration

thats why, we need another additional plugin to handle foreground notification on Android. there are many option plugin in pub.dev , but they recommend to use
[flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)  package

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;

  // If `onMessage` is triggered with a notification, construct our own
  // local notification to show to users using the created channel.
  if (notification != null && android != null) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel.id,
            channel.name,
            channel.description,
            icon: android?.smallIcon,
            // other properties...
          ),
        ));
  }
});
```

please read the documentation for detail setup